# The connection cannot be completed in Linux boost::asio::spawn

Tags: linux, boost-asio, asio

If the server starts after the connection cannot be reached.why?
boost_1_73_0、Linux operating system

```cpp
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/spawn.hpp"

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    auto ep        = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 1560);
    bool isConnect = false;
    bool isRun     = false;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ctx);
    while (true) {
        if (!isConnect && !isRun) {
            boost::asio::spawn([&](boost::asio::yield_context y) {
                isRun = true;
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                socket.async_connect(ep, y[ec]);
                if (ec) {
                    isRun = false;
                    socket.close();
                    printf("close\n");
                } else {
                    isConnect = true;
                    printf("connect\n");
                }
            });
        }
        ctx.poll_one();
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

It works fine on windows.
My post looks mostly code, so I added this sentence.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

### First Things First

[`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) is a WinAPI call. It expects milliseconds.

I suspect you might have ported this to Linux by... lowercasing `Sleep` to `sleep`. However [`sleep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/sleep.html) takes seconds. So you might be waiting 1000s each poll.

Fixing that by not using any platform-specific calls but instead using standard library functions already seems to "work" on my machine:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a64bce149570cb45)**

```cpp
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/spawn.hpp"
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    auto ep        = tcp::endpoint({}, 1560);
    bool             isConnect = false, isRun = false;
    tcp::socket      socket(ctx);
    while (true) {
        if (!isConnect && !isRun) {
            asio::spawn([&](asio::yield_context y) {
                isRun = true;
                error_code ec;
                socket.async_connect(ep, y[ec]);
                if (ec) {
                    isRun = false;
                    socket.close();
                    std::cout << ec.message() << ": close" << std::endl;
                } else {
                    isConnect = true;
                    std::cout << ec.message() << ": connect" << std::endl;
                }
            });
        }
        ctx.poll_one();
        sleep_for(1s);
    }
}
```

[image]

### Next: Choose Your Context!

You `spawn` without a context. This means it will default to a strand of the associated executor of the spawned function. There is none, so `system_executor` is defaulted. You can see this by printing the effective executor from inside the coro:

```
std::cerr << boost::core::demangle(y.get_executor().target_type().name()) << std::endl;
```

Which will print

```cpp
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::basic_system_executor<
    boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::possibly_t<0>,
    boost::asio::execution::detail::relationship::fork_t<0>, std::allocator<void>>>
```

With `spawn(ctx, ...)` you'd see instead:

```cpp
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::basic_executor_type<std::allocator<void>, 0ul>>
```

What it means is that `ctx.poll()` never runs **anything** related to your coro or socket, because they're in a different [execution context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/execution_context.html).

> *Alternatively you may fix it by binding your executor to the coro function with `bind_executor(ctx.get_executor, [&](...) {...})`*

### Why Did It Appear To Work?

It appeared to work above, because at least on Linux `system_executor` defaults to a thread pool which runs their threads in the background.

This is scary, because it made your program multi-threaded without you knowing: You had potential data-races waiting to happen on all the shared objects, as well as the problem that the loads of the boolean flags could easily be optimized in such a way that a change would never be detected.

### What's The Goal

However, it's unclear what the poll loop accomplishes, really. You can simplify a lot by just taking the spawn out of the loop, and replacing the loop with the much more robust `run()`/`run_for()`:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3a2835c29a39a4e)**

```
int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::socket      socket(ctx);

    tcp::endpoint ep{{}, 1560};
    asio::spawn(ctx, [&](asio::yield_context y) {
        std::cerr << boost::core::demangle(y.get_executor().target_type().name()) << std::endl;

        error_code ec;
        socket.async_connect(ep, y[ec]);
        if (ec) {
            socket.close();
            std::cout << ec.message() << ": close" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << ec.message() << ": connect" << std::endl;
        }
    });

    ctx.run_for(10s); // max 10s
}
```

This works correctly and without multiple threads.

### UPDATE: Retrying The Connection?

I had a sudden brainwave and realized that *maybe* you want to retry the connection UNTIL it succeeds. In that case you can just put the loop inside the coroutine:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7fc142fb1854770)**

```cpp
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/asio/spawn.hpp"
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp::socket      socket(ctx);

    tcp::endpoint ep{{}, 1560};
    asio::spawn(ctx, [&](asio::yield_context y) {
        error_code ec = asio::error::connection_refused;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
            socket.async_connect(ep, y[ec]);
            std::cout << "attempt #" << i << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (!ec.failed())
                break;
            sleep_for(500ms);
        }
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    });

    ctx.run();
}
```

With online demo:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_{thread,coroutine,context} 
(./a.out; ./a.out)&
(sleep 3; nc -tklp 1560 -w2 <<< "Hello there!")
wait
```

Outputting:

```
attempt #1: Connection refused
attempt #2: Software caused connection abort
attempt #3: Connection refused
attempt #4: Software caused connection abort
attempt #5: Connection refused
attempt #6: Software caused connection abort
attempt #7: Success

attempt #1: Success
```

Local demo for interactive output:

[image]

### Async Sleep

To avoid blocking the io context with the `sleep_for` calls, use a waitable timer: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91199229ebb13f2f)**

```
asio::steady_timer(socket.get_executor(), 500ms).async_wait(y);
```

Comment: Oh... the while loop might have been a way to RETRY connection after failure. In that case, make the retry loop part of the coroutine! Added that to the answer text with demos as well

Comment: I'm curious whether you've found this answer or just forgot about the question :)